# Why does Azure Data Factory use AppendFile instead of PutBlob to write files to blob storage container?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, rest

I've got a Log Analytics Workspace stood up and created some (blob) Diagnostic Settings for some Azure Storage Accounts. Now I'm analyzing the blob traffic.

Seems that the various methods of getting blobs into blob storage (Azure Data Factory (ADF), Azure Storage Explorer (ASE), Python SDK, etc.) use different API methods out-of-the-box.

**Example:**

- I'm seeing that all files uploaded using ADF are using the `AppendFile` `OperationName`

[image]

- Whereas all files uploaded using ASE use the `PutBlob` `OperationName`

**Question:**

- Is `AppendFile` a method that was explicitly set on the ADF side?
- Or is it the default when writing blobs from ADF to blob storage?

Also, I don't see `AppendFile` listed as a method in the [Blob Service REST API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api).

- Is this just an ADF thing or is the method missing from the docs?

Comment: Which activity did you use in ADF?

Comment: Its a different team which writes to the container with ADF. I have no idea.

Comment: Looking through the logs a bit more, I think ADF is using `AzureDataFactoryCopy`. In the `StorageBlobLogs` table, I'm seeing `UserAgentHeader: AzureDataFactoryCopy`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, I suppose your storage account is a [Data Lake Storage Gen2 account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction) i.e. `Hierarchical namespace` was enabled like below.

[image]

When you use the [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in ADF to copy blobs between containers(also named filesystem in datalake gen2), it will call the  Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST API instead of the normal Storage REST API - [Path - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update), if you look into the `Uri` parameter in the log, you will find its format is like below.

[image]

It is the same as the REST API sample, because it essentially calls this API.

[image]

Even if it is a Data Lake Storage Gen2 account, the normal Storage REST API also works for it, so if you use something like Azure Storage Explorer, it essentially calls the normal Storage REST API directly i.e. [`Put blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob).

Comment: The different REST API's used by each system (ADF vs. ASE vs. Python SDK vs. Flow, etc.) causes some challenges with EventGrid Function triggers as well as with LogAnalytics.

Comment: I don't quite understand **why** ADF would use an "append" action to create a new file. Would be nice to have some intuition around this. Do you know *why* the ADF copy action does this PATCH instead of just PUT?

Comment: @ericOnline It is related to the [linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services), your colleague uses the [`Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage) linked service, so it calls the ADLS Gen2 REST API.

Comment: @ericOnline If he uses [Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) linked service, then it will call the normal azure storage REST API i.e. the Put one. (Even if the storage account is an ADLS Gen2 one, the normal  azure storage REST API can also be used for it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Azure Data Factory Flow and the primary id  is the same,  it usually does the AppendFile operation

Comment: Right. This post asks "Why?".